# Dynamically append data to form post

Tags: javascript, forms, http, post, dynamic

working with an html form, with a "post" method, is there a way to instruct the browser to dynamically add data (once client posts the form) to a post WITHOUT it being in the form of an input elements' name value pairs? Could you use javascript/jquery/ajax to just say, when this form gets posted, append some characters?

Comment: what do you mean by 'characters', that is not a name value pair? Do you want to suffix an existing name value pair? Or do you want to add another name value pair, only not by means of appending another input element to the DOM?

Comment: i want to know how to add name value pair without appending another input element, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="sbmForm1();return false;">
<input type="text" name="var1" value="value1" />
<input type="text" name="var2" value="value3" />
<input type="submit" name="sbm-btn" value="send" />
</form>
```

In javascript function sbmForm1 you can add parameter and send them via ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.yoururl.com/script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#form1').serialize() + '&yournewvar=yournewvalue',
        success: function(msg) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

You need jquery to do this request!

Comment: this is what i was looking for, but is it possible to do this while putting the url as an attribute inside the form element (action=url), instead of  using a form inline onsubmit handler?

Comment: @Sam: You could put `url: $('#form1').attr('action')`, and you would not have to specify the URL twice. This would behave just like a regular form submit in most respects. But then, I think appending a hidden field to the DOM would seem even less invasive...

Answer (score 1):

You can Use XMLHttpRequest Javascript object to do this. Go to mozilla developer docs to see the api of this object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use serializeArray(), which allows you to add data to a JSON structure:

```
var form = $('#form1');

form = form.serializeArray();

form = form.concat([
    {name: "customer_id", value: window.username},
    {name: "post_action", value: "Update Information"}
]);

$.post('/change-user-details', form, function(d) {
    if (d.error) {
        alert("There was a problem updating your user details")
    } 
});
```